# += operator on a float return an empty numpy array instead of throwing TypeError

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let's say if I want to iteratively append floats to a list L, I can use `L.append` in a `for` loop. I was messing around with the operator `+=` (which I take it as `L.extend`) and did the following:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

def calculate_R2(X,y):
    reg = LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(X,y)
    score = reg.score(X,y)

    return score

y = [1,2,3]

score = []
for ind in range(10):
    X = np.random.rand(3,1)
    score+=calculate_R2(X,y)
```

Since `calculate_R2(X,y)` returns a float, I would expect the first iteration of the `for` loop would fail and throw a `TypeError` that a float object is not iterable. However, the script runs without error, and returns `score` as

`array([], dtype=float64)`

Now, I just dont understand why this happens. If I replace the function `calculate_R2(X,y)` by another function `add(x)`, the script does throw the correct error message (`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`):

```
def add(x):
    return x+10

score = []
for ind in range(10):
    score+=add(ind)
```

I am using python 2.7 and sklearn version 0.18.1 on Spyder. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: what is `type(calculate_R2(X,y))`

Comment: perhaps the `reg.score(X, y)` returns a `np.array`. So basically you do `[] + np.array([13])` which gives `array([], dtype=float64)`

Comment: type(calculate_R2(X,y)) is a numpy.float64 instead of a numpy array

Comment: I got it. Adding a numpy.float64 to a list works as adding a float to np.array.

Comment: Thanks, was just about to say that after reading your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Python list + Python int or float

During the first iteration, your `score` variable is a plain Python list. You're right, adding an int or a float would fail with a TypeError:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] + 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

## Python list + np.float

`calculate_R2` returns a `numpy.float64`. Adding a `numpy.float64` to a Python list adds the float to every element and returns a `np.array`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> [1, 2, 3] + np.float64(3.14)
array([ 4.14,  5.14,  6.14])
```

BTW, you shouldn't use the same variable name for two distinct object. Your collection of `score`s could be called `scores`.

## np.array + scalar

Adding a scalar to a numpy array doesn't append anything. It adds the scalar to every element of the array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3]) + 1
array([2, 3, 4])
```

If you do it on an empty array, it adds the scalar to every element of the empty array, and returns the corresponding array:

```
>>> np.array([]) + 1
array([], dtype=float64)
```

Comment: In this case it is adding a numpy float to an empty list works like adding a float to an empty numpy array. I will accept your answer regardless. Thanks!

Comment: @lizardfireman: It's always good to wait before accepting. I'm still editing the answer.